# Variable local dt as datatable, el valor de tipo data table no se puede convertir en datatable

Tags: vb.net

Hola tengo el siguiente código en el cual quiero hacer una consulta a una base de datos para que cual tengo definida una variable declarada como `dim dt as new datatable` y cuando la llamo mas abajo para que me regrese dicho valor me dice que la variable no se puede convertir en datatable, también me dice que me puede regresar valores nulos.

```
Public Function consultarCliente(numID As String) As DataTable()
    Try
        conectar()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select ID, Nombres, TELEFONO FROM CLIENTES WHERE NUM_ID='" & numID & "'")

        cmd.Connection = con
        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            adp.Fill(dt)

            Return dt



        Else
            Return Nothing

        End If



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: gracias ya quedo resulto mi problema